# Manipulate CSV value without knowing column names

Tags: powershell, csv

My script has to read in a CSV file and search for any value (other than the headers) which contains string longer than specific characters, and cut out the exceeding characters if found. And then write the whole data back as CSV file using `Export-Csv` again, with headers preserved. Input CSV files are all well-formed, with headers, however header names are variant among files and therefore cannot be determined in advance.

So far all `Import-Csv` relevant code samples/solutions I google'd need known column names, such as:

```
Import-Csv "file1.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.aKnownColumnName -eq "someCondition") { doSomething() }
}
```

Is there a way to deal with my requirement above?

Comment: To clarify - You want to trim any value in any column if it is longer than some length, unless it is a column header?

Comment: @Snak3d0c Number of columns might change over time.

Comment: Note that for passing the current object downstream the pipeline you need to output it in the `ForEach-Object` loop. A line with just `$_` at the end of the loop will suffice for that.

Comment: `((ipcsv '.\file.csv')[0].PSObject.Properties).Name`